# Eclipse Paho - MQTT Javascript - how access onMessageArrived from outside

Tags: javascript, mqtt, paho

I am using Eclipse Paho - Mqtt javascript library.

Trying to access `onMessageArrived` from outside function:

```
  mqttConnect(){
    var client = new Paho.MQTT.Client("wss://test.mqtt.address", "myClientId");
    this.connectionInfo = client;
    client.onConnectionLost = onConnectionLost;
    client.onMessageArrived = onMessageArrived;
    client.connect({onSuccess:onConnect});

    function onConnect() {
        client.subscribe("some/path/to/subscribe/");
    }
    function onConnectionLost(responseObject) {
        if (responseObject.errorCode !== 0) {
            console.log("onConnectionLost:"+responseObject.errorMessage);
        }
    }
    function onMessageArrived(message) {
        console.log("onMessageArrived: "+message.payloadString);
        return message.payloadString; //this does not work of course.
    }
  }
```

Trying to access messages from outside like:

```
_constract(){
  var message = mqttConnect();
  console.log(message);

}
```

Maybe register some global variable and put it there like `this.global = message.payloadString` ?

Answer (score 0):

You either store the message payload in a global variable so you can access it again later or you do all the processing you need from within the `onMessageArrived()` callback.

It has to be this way because `onMessageArrived()` is asynchronous, it may never be called, or it may be called many times entirely dependent on the message rate on that topic.

EDIT (example):

```
var client;
var lastMsg;

function connect(){
  client = new Paho.MQTT.Client("wss://test.mqtt.address", "myClientId");

  client.onConnectionLost = onConnectionLost;
  client.onMessageArrived = onMessageArrived;
  client.connect({onSuccess:onConnect});
}

function onConnect() {
  client.subscribe("some/path/to/subscribe/");
}

function onConnectionLost(responseObject) {
  if (responseObject.errorCode !== 0) {
    console.log("onConnectionLost:"+responseObject.errorMessage);
  }
}

function onMessageArrived(message) {
  console.log("onMessageArrived: "+message.payloadString);
  lastMsg = message.payloadString;
}

connect();

setInterval(function() {
  document.findElementById("foo").innerHTML = lastMsg;
}, 5000);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Could you please give me example?

Comment: @mr_e30 example added